# parseInt returns NaN

Tags: javascript, parseint

spent 45min trying figure why it returns NaN, please point me to the right direction.
My code is:

```html
<form name="calc">
  <input type="text" value="0" name="first" onchange="add()">
  <input type="text" value="0" name="second" onchange="add()">
  <input type="text" name="result" onchange="add()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = parseInt(document.calc.first.value);
  var b = parseInt(document.calc.second.value);
  var c = a + b;
  function add(){
    document.calc.result.value = parseInt(c);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: But it doesn’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
function add() {
  var a = parseInt(document.calc.first.value, 10);
  var b = parseInt(document.calc.second.value, 10);

  var c = a + b;

  document.calc.result.value = c;
}
```

You have to re-read `a` and `b` values each time they're changed.

**Note 1**: Also, remember about `radix` parameter in `parseInt(val, radix)`. It's `10` in your case (as I suppose). See [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_Interpretations_with_No_Radix) on why that's important.

**Note 2**: no need to call `parseInt(c)`, because `c` is already of the type `number`.

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` are calculated *once* at page load, when the form is still empty, obviously the result will be `NaN`.

Put all the logic in the `add` function, so you retrieve the current state of the form.